# Program that prints prime numbers

Tags: c, recursion, struct, primes, function-definition

Program that prints the 2 largest prime numbers in a given range from the user using recursion.
I want to get the 2 largest prime numbers in a range that is given by the user, but somehow it just prints the consecutive numbers in the range. The prime checker in my code is working when I built a program that asks the user for the end number, checks if it is a prime number and prints all prime numbers from 1 to n. But when I plugged it in this code, its not working well. I tried researching for other codes to be my reference but I cant find anything that prints the 2 largest prime numbers. It doesn't matter if the users input are prime numbers or not, the code will just check the two largest prime numbers in between. The end number or y can also be printed if its a prime number. I'm also trying to not use arrays to practice my parameter passing.

In this code, I'm trying to get the 2 largest prime number and print it. You can see the num1, and num2 are unused, they are supposed to be the variables for the 2 largest prime numbers in the given range.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void usersInput(int *x, int *y);
void swapping(int *x, int *y);
int primeCheck(int i, int j);

int main() {
    int x, y, i, j, num1, num2;
    
    usersInput(&x, &y);

    if (x > y) {
        swapping(&x, &y);
    }

    printf("The value of x is %d, and the value of y is %d.\n", x, y);

    printf("\nThe two largest prime numbers from %d to %d are : ", x, y);
    for (i = x; i <= y; i++)
        if (primeCheck(i, y) == 0)
            printf("%d ", i);

    return 0;
}

void usersInput(int *x, int *y) {

    printf("Enter the value of x: ");
    scanf("%d", x);
    printf("Enter the value of y: ");
    scanf("%d", y);
}

void swapping(int *x, int *y) {
    int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

int primeCheck(int i, int j) {
    if (j == i) {
        return 0;
    } else if (j % i == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return primeCheck(i + 1, j);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I don't have any functions yet for getting the 2 largest prime numbers. I don't really have idea on how to, so please help me

Here's the actual output:

```
Enter the value of x: 10
Enter the value of y: 3
The value of x is 3, and the value of y is 10.
The two largest prime numbers from 3 to 10 are: 6 7 8 9 10
```

Here's the expected output

```
Enter the value of x: 10
Enter the value of y: 3
The value of x is 3, and the value of y is 10.
The two largest prime numbers from 3 to 10 are: 5 7
```

Comment: As `primeCheck()` functions incorrectly, I recommend to get `primeCheck()` to work first before attempting "to report the 2 largest primes.  I recommend to start with an non-recursive code first to get the function correct.  Tip: with `int primeCheck()`, only `int primeCheck(int i)` is needed.

Comment: Is this a class assignment? This is possibly the slowest way to check for primes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the test for primality `if (primeCheck(i, y) == 0)` is incorrect: you should pass `2` as the first argument and `i` as the second.
- the loop should start at `i = y` and run while `i >= x`, decrementing `i` to find the largest primes in the range first.
- you should store the primes and stop when 2 have been found.
- the primality test function should be modified to return `1` if `i > j` to prevent infinite recursion on some inputs, such as `primeCheck(2, 1)`.
- testing divisors up to and including sqrt(j) is sufficient in `primeCheck()`. You can stop the recursion when `j < i * i`, which can be tested without potential overflow as `j / i < i`.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int usersInput(int *x, int *y);
void swapping(int *x, int *y);
int primeCheck(int i, int j);

int main() {
    int x, y, i, num1, num2;
    
    if (!usersInput(&x, &y)) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (x > y) {
        swapping(&x, &y);
    }

    printf("The value of x is %d, and the value of y is %d.\n", x, y);

    for (i = y, num1 = num2 = 0; i >= x; i--) {
        if (primeCheck(2, i) == 0) {
            if (num2 == 0) {
                num2 = i;
            } else {
                num1 = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The two largest prime numbers from %d to %d are: %.0d %.0d\n",
            x, y, num1, num2);
    return 0;
}

// read user input return zero on failure
int usersInput(int *x, int *y) {
    printf("Enter the value of x: ");
    if (scanf("%d", x) != 1)
       return 0;
    printf("Enter the value of y: ");
    return scanf("%d", y) == 1;
}

void swapping(int *x, int *y) {
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

int primeCheck(int i, int j) {
    if (j < 2) {
        return 1;  // negative, 0 or 1: not prime
    } else if (j / i < i) {
        return 0;  // all factors tested up to sqrt(j): j is prime
    } else if (j % i == 0) {
        return 1;  // composite, not prime
    } else {
        return primeCheck(i + 1, j);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the value of x: 10
Enter the value of y: 3
The value of x is 3, and the value of y is 10.
The two largest prime numbers from 3 to 10 are: 5 7
```

Answer (score 2):

The sub-statement of this if statement that is the call of `printf`:

```
 if (primeCheck(i,y)==1)
            printf("%d ", i);
```

gets the control when the function `primeCheck` returns `1`.

But according to the function definition it returns `1` when `y` is divisible by any number in the range `[i, y]` and it is not necessary that this number is `i`:

```
} else if (j%i==0) {
    return 1;
```

In all other case the function returns 0.

As the function calls itself recursively then it returns 1 when at least for one number in the range [x, y] y is divisible by that number.

For example for your input the function always will return 1 for each number if the range [3, 5] because 10 is divisible by 5.

Actually your function does not make a sense and has nothing common with prime numbers.

Also pay attention to that to find two biggest prime numbers in a range you should start the loop from the biggest number down to the smallest number of the range.

I think you understand the assignment incorrectly. It seems you need to write non-recursive function that determines whether a give number is a prime number and write a recursive function instead of the for loop that returns two greatest prime numbers.

That is the function that recursively finds two greatest prime numbers can look something like shown in the demonstration program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct TwoPrimes
{
    unsigned int first_prime;
    unsigned int second_prime;
};

int is_prime( unsigned int n );

struct TwoPrimes find_two_primes( unsigned int first, unsigned int last )
{
    if (first == last)
    {
        struct TwoPrimes two_primes = { ( is_prime( first ) ? last : 0 ), 0 };
        return two_primes;
    }
    else
    {
        struct TwoPrimes two_primes = find_two_primes( first + 1, last );

        if (two_primes.first_prime == 0 || two_primes.second_prime == 0)
        {
            if (is_prime( first ))
            {
                if (two_primes.first_prime == 0)
                {
                    two_primes.first_prime = first;
                }
                else
                {
                    two_primes.second_prime = first;
                }
            }
        }

        return two_primes;
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    struct TwoPrimes two_primes = find_two_primes( 3, 10 );

    if (two_primes.first_prime != 0)
    {
        printf( "%u\n", two_primes.first_prime );

        if (two_primes.second_prime != 0)
        {
            printf( "%u\n", two_primes.second_prime );
        }
    }
}
```

What you need to do yourself is to define the function `is_prime`.

Comment: thank you for the feedback, can you help me to correct my mistakes to make my code run? or make my function to have sense with prime numbers?

Comment: @User617290653251457439 You need to write at first a separate iterative function that indeed check whether a given number is a prime number. And then convert it to a recursive function.

Comment: I made it equal to 0. I'm experimenting before I posted this question, I forgot to edit it back to 0

Comment: When I made the ```if (primeCheck(i,y)==0)``` equal to zero, the actual output also changed. pls see the edited code